# How can I click in buttons while doing for loop?

Tags: javascript, loops, for-loop

I have buttons with same class name and I want to click them while looping.
I wrote something like that, but it does not work. It click only 1 button

```
let btns = document.getElementsByClassName('key');

for (let i = 0; i < btns.length; i++) {
    btns[i].click();
};
```

Comment: Can you add your full code, including html, to your question?

Comment: Your code looks correct, however make sure that the script runs when the DOM has loaded.

Answer (score 0):

See this [working example](https://codepen.io/RaysOfTheSun/pen/QZOvdL?editors=1111). Also here's a reference to [EventTarget.dispatchEvent()](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/EventTarget/dispatchEvent)

```js
window.onload = ()=>{
  // get all our buttons
  let buttons = document.getElementsByClassName('button-clickers');
  // the event we plan on invoking
  let clickEvent = new Event('click');
  // assign an event handler for each button
  for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].addEventListener('click', function(){
      console.log(`hi, you have triggered ${this.value}'s click event.`);
    });
  }
  // trigger the click event for each button
  for(let i = 0; i < buttons.length; i++){
    buttons[i].dispatchEvent(clickEvent);
    // buttons[i].click(); // This works too.
  }
}
```

```html
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt1">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt2">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt3">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt4">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt5">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt6">
<input type="button" class="button-clickers" value="Bnt7">
```

Your problem might be with the way you were acquiring all the buttons or assigning the event handlers to them. If they were dynamically created, were you sure that the event handler was assigned after the button was created? :)